# Can I test a variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I am currently working on a business review application project. I need to create a function that handles filtering businesses based on location or category (I am currently using dummy data).I have successfully added filtering by location. Istanbul test reports say I have one line uncovered in my one of my functions (messing up my shine of having 100% coverage). Here is the filter function.

```
import Models from '../models/Models';
import SendResponse from '../SendResponse';

const { Businesses } = Models;

const Filter = (req, res) => {
    const { location, category } = req.query;
    const theBusinesses = [];

    let theQuery;

    if (location) { //this line remains uncovered
        theQuery = location;
    }

    Businesses.forEach((business) => {
        if (business.state === theQuery) {
            theBusinesses.push(business);
        }
    });
    if (theBusinesses.length === 0) {
        return SendResponse(res, 404, `There are currently no businesses in ${theQuery}`);
    }
    return SendResponse(res, 200, `Found ${theBusinesses.length} businesses`, theBusinesses);
};

export default Filter;
```

Here are the tests I have written for the filter function:

```
describe('FILTER BY LOCATION TESTS', () => {
  describe('When a user sends a GET request to /api/v1/businesses?<location>', () => {
    it('Response message should equal "Found 1 businesses"', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/businesses?location=Lagos')
            .end((req, res) => {
                assert.equal(res.body.message, 'Found 1 businesses');
                done();
            });
    });

    it('It should return 1 business', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/businesses?location=Lagos')
            .end((req, res) => {
                res.body.responseObject.length.should.equal(1);
                done();
            });
    });

    it('It should return a 404 status', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/businesses?location=Enugu')
            .end((req, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(404);
                done();
            });
    });
  });
});
```

and a picture of my nyc istanbul report:

[image: nyc istanbul report]

How do I test just this uncovered line?

Comment: You don't, you test the behavior of the function--that's what unit testing does.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I read more on this after posting the question. Perhaps, I should edit the question topic.

Comment: No need. The miss was not testing the method in its entirety as noted in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line tests if location has a value. Since you're always passing a location in all your test cases, the other branch path of the condition i.e. where location is blank, is not covered/tested.

So try a test case which invokes the API without passing the location parameter value.

```
it('It should return a 404 status when location is not provided', (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/businesses?location=')
            .end((req, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(404);
                done();
            });
    });
```

But your source code is a bit inefficient for this scenario. It still does a pointless iteration on Businesses. Maybe you should add an `else` to the `if (location)` clause and return a `400` response code, because this is really a request issue.

Comment: Woops! Like magic! It is now covered. I didn't just learn to fix my problem, I also learnt a new approach to problem solving  - driven by the way you responded.

About the inefficiency, if loop through Businesses, how do I extract businesses with the location in the search query?

Comment: Your current loop code is fine. It's just that it executes unnecessarily in the case when location is blank, because you already _know_ it is not going to match anything in the loop.

Comment: Oh! I understand perfectly now. Thank you very much. I would refactor.